# Am I overstaying my Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas, overstaying, 90-180-visa-rules

I have heard there's a 90 days in every 180 days rule about staying in the Schengen zone, but there are also rumours about resetting the time, so I thought of asking here what's the case exactly.

I stayed in Germany Nov 25th 2018 - Dec 16th 2018 (22 days), and again Jan 10th 2019 - Apr 9th 2019 (90 days). Am I overstaying my tourist visa?

Comment: It is "no more than 90 days in **any** 180 days". There is no reset, it a continuous 'rolling' rule.

Comment: @Andy Gondzer You need to exit the Schengen area by 18 March at the absolute latest. Remaining until 9 April means you would spend a total of 112 days in the preceding 180 day period in Germany, resulting in an overstay of 22 days starting from 19 March.